# "No connectivity with the server" for files in only one content DB?

Tags: 2010, content-database, connection

SharePoint 2010 / SQL Server 2008 R2

One of my users reported a problem opening files yesterday.  Upon opening a file she would receive this string of error messages:
[image: No Connectivity 1]
Clicking "Retry Open" leads to:
[image]
Then clicking "OK" brings up:
[image]
Clicking "OK" there just leaves you with Excel (or whatever the appropriate program) at a dark grey background without a document loaded.

I've split up my site collection by departments and each departments' document libraries are on their own content databases.  This problem is only occurring in the Operations CDB.  I can replicate the errors on my machine.

Here's where things get more interesting- If I open Windows Explorer and navigate to the parent folder of that .xlsx file and then rename the file (or create a copy with a unique name) then that renamed (or copied) file will open just fine.  You can then rename either of those files to the original file name and it will once again fail to open.

What's going on here?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this

Answer (score 0):

This is going to sound really crazy but this worked for me.  Have the last person who edited the file do a check out via the UI, then immediately undo the checkout.  Now open your copy of Excel and make sure that you do not have the 'Save Thumbnails' option selected.  You should now be able to open the file.

Comment: Sorry, no dice. :\

Comment: Worth a shot.  If you can reproduce this easily enough, it might be time to get Microsoft involved as they can provide the proper SQL queries that can highlight where this might be happening.  If you do bring them in, can you please post the details here?  I know you are not the only person who has this issue, though you do seem to be the only one that can regularly reproduce it, which is essential when dealing with Microsoft Support.